# Is the theme of Captain Jack's "Dream a Dream" music video intended to be a Fifth Element homage?

Tags: the-fifth-element, music-video

### Captain Jack's "Dream a Dream"

Recently, Captain Jack's "Dream a Dream" popped into my head, courtesy of memories of doing the song in Dance Dance Revolution. The official music video was linked and I watched through it and I was struck that several elements seemed to be homages to Luc Besson's *The Fifth Element*. Is there any proof that this was intentional?

Bandaged women from "Dream a Dream": [image: Bandaged women from "Dream a Dream"]

Leeloo from The Fifth Element in similar bandage garb: [image: Leeloo in bandage garb]

Captain Jack in military garb with red hat: [image: Captain Jack - military garb - red hat]

General Tudor in military garb with red hat: [image: General Tudor - Fifth Element]

Comment: Most English-speaking people won't recognize the acronym for Deutsche Demokratische Republik; just call it East Germany.

Comment: Sorry. I'll expand out the acronym of DDR for Dance Dance Revolution. ^_^

Comment: I'd note that Captain Jack's outfit is pretty much the same as he always wore, so that's less likely to be a reference. I'm not sure about the rest though.

Comment: @ConMan: 
Ah. So it might just be coincidence. Honestly, the strap-dress was the big thing for me, and probably influenced me seeing more than there was.

Comment: - The thermal bandage dress

 - The flipping tumbling routine that Leelo does in her fight with the Mangalores

 - The flying car that ends up landing in a cloud of deep fog

 - His chair turn at the start (similar to the President of Earth's introduction)

Comment: I sent a message to the official email address for the group, asking if they could confirm, deny, or provide additional details.